# Add bootstrap's nav-pills background color

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar with single elements being `nav-pills`. I recompiled bootstrap to change the default colors. Now I'd like to add a background color to the pills different from the hover and active ones. How to do it? Should I force it via app-wide css file? Is there a way to achieve it via bootstrap's **less**?

This is a snippet of my current navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse elements">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
        <li ng-class="setClass('/')"><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-class="setClass('/list')"><a href="/list">Browse</a></li>
        <li ng-class="setClass('/search')"><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

As you can see, the hovered element get a nice highlighting, the active one is clearly visible, while the not active is kind of lost in the background.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What you want to see?

Comment: I want to see your attempt. Isn't your output? Then give the code.

Comment: you could use the customize tool to modify colours as you please (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) - of course you can also modify the LESS file and re-generate the CSS file (which is what the customize tool does for you)

Comment: That's my output. Nothing fancy here, just plain bootstrap. Btw, not really a code problem. More a phylosofical question, i.e. where should I force the background for the nav-pill? in my app-wide css file, in the recompiled bootstap css or there is a way to acheive it via less. Anyway I'm editing to include the html code for the navbar.

Comment: first close the /ul tag

Comment: because of some cutting/pasting the </ul> tag was cut away. nice catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default `nav-pills` don't have a default background color, you need to set one yourself. There is no option in bootstraps default less configuration.

So why not just setting:

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    background: #f6f6f6;  /* your preferred color */
}
```

I would put it in another css file - not in bootstraps css or less file. Because once you want to update bootstrap you can always do it quickly with a configuration json, but you would have to remember and set all css/less changes again - or they would be lost.
For better structure of your files, you can create a *bootstrap_extended.css* file (or something like that), where you only put in code extending or overwriting bootstrap defaults not configurable on the customization page.

You could also create a *bootstrap_extended.**less*** file and put

```
@import (inline) '../Content/bootstrap.less';
```

at the top, so you just use/compile your file and would create a final and already extended single css for bootstrap.